# AES_128_GCM: Decrypting IV in Lua

Tags: java, lua, cryptography

I have to decrypt a message encrypted by an other party in Java using AES-128-GCM.

They gave me the code they are using for encrypt/decrypt functions, but I, having almost no background in cryptography, don't understand this line:

```
javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec iv = new javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec(128, ivbyte);
```

It is used both in encrypt and decrypt.

What does it do? How can I translate this to Lua on our side?

Answer (score 0):

It is an [Initialization Vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) used to create randomization

Comment: That I understand. But the function takes IV as an input parameter and does something with it. My understanding is it changes it in some (reversible by the same function) way. I need to understand the algorithm used by the function to change the IV both ways so that I can replicate it on our side.

Comment: @E_the_Shy If you want to understand how GCM works, then please read the specification. It's not something that can be answered in a few paragraphs. If you still have a problem with understand the cryptography behind it, then you can ask a *specific* question on [crypto.se] after reading the specification. If you're asking about code, then you need to ask here on [so].

Comment: @E_the_Shy You supply the same iv both for encryption and decryption.

Comment: See http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/gcm/gcm-spec.pdf for details of GCM mode.